# Automate the Boring Stuff With Python. Comma Code

Tags: python

In *Automate the Boring Stuff With Python*, there is a practice project called Comma Code:

> Say you have a list value like this:
>
> ```
> spam = ['apples', 'bananas', 'tofu', 'cats']
> ```
>
> Write a function that takes a list value as an argument and returns
>   a string with all the items separated by a comma and a space, with 'and'
>   inserted before the last item. For example, passing the previous spam list to
>   the function would return 'apples, bananas, tofu, and cats'. But your function
>   should be able to work with any list value passed to it.

This is what I made:

```
y = ['apples', 'bananas', 'tofu', 'cats']
def function(x):
    x.insert(-1, ('and ' + x[-1]))
    del x[-1]
    numbers = len(x)
    spam = x[0]
    for i in range(1,numbers):
        spam = spam + ', ' + x[i]
    print(spam)

function(y)
```

The function works with any list value, and I've done all that it asked, but what I want to know is if there was a better way to do this, or if it was asking for something different than this.  I'd also like to know what is bad about my code. I started reading this book a few days ago so I'm completely new to coding.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is really much too broad for Stack Overflow, which deals with more focussed coding problems than this.  For advice on improving working code, consider [codereview.se] instead - but do read [A guide to Code Review for Stack Overflow users](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5778) first.

Comment: I'll upvote the first answer that preserves your Oxford comma :)

Comment: I agree with the others, though. Fully working code should be posted on Code Review, not StackOverflow. I recommend doing so.

Comment: This concerns reviewing the style of working code, and may better suit at [codereview.se]. Stack Overflow specializes in not-working code.

Answer (score 2):

Solution comes to mind:

```
# do add conditions to return list if len is <2
# perhaps return " and ".join(l) if len == 2
" ".join([", ".join(l[:-1] + ["and"]), l[-1]])
'a, b, and c'
```

Answer (score 1):

As this is your first time coding, why not do it this way? This is something that you can understand and "feels intuitive".

```
y = ['apples', 'bananas', 'tofu', 'cats']
def create_description(items_list):
    description = ""
    for item in items_list[:-1]: #everything except for the last element
      description = description + item + ", "
    description = description + "and " + items_list[-1] # add the last item
    return description
print(create_description(y))
```

Note that if you only have one item it is printed as `and last_item`.

Answer (score 1):

Very basic approach, and thats why I like it:

```
a = ", ".join(y[:-1]) + " and " + y[-1]
```

`join` all list elements but the last one, and add this by string adding.

Answer (score 1):

This is a very simple solution to the problem:

```
spam = ['apples', 'bananas', 'tofu', 'cats']

def items(things):
    for i in range(len(things) - 1):
        print(things[i] + ', ', end='')
    print('and ' + things[-1])

items(spam)
```

Answer (score 1):

this is my code:

```
spam = ['apples', 'bananas', 'tofu', 'cats']

def what_in_list(spam):
    spam[-1] = 'and ' + spam[-1]
    content_in_list = ''
    for i in spam:
        content_in_list += i + ',' + ' '
    print("'" + content_in_list[:-2] + "'.")

what_in_list(spam)
```

Answer (score 1):

Using only what you would know from, "Automate the Boring Stuff with Python."

```
spam = ['apples', 'bananas' , 'tofu', 'cats']

def commaCode(listValue):
    for i in range(len(listValue)-1):
        print(listValue[i], end=', ') # the end keyword argument was presented in ch.(3)
    print('and ' + listValue[-1])

commaCode(spam)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, please review: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Answer (score 1):

I know this is kind of an old question but I am also just learning to code with this book. Here is the code I came up with using this book, stack overflow, and various other resources. I'm a beginner so it is what it is. I'm sure there's a more efficient code to do this.

This code will keep on asking the add, remove, and restate question so you can keep on adjusting the list. That is until you quit.

```
import sys

myList = ['apples', 'bananas', 'tofu', 'cats']

def items(myList):
    for i in range(len(myList) - 1):
        print(myList[i] + ', ', end ='')
    print('and ' + myList[-1])

def change():
    while True:
        print()        #print() gives it a blank space
        n = input("""
Do you want to add or remove from the list?

Do you want to restate the list?

    Type N to exit,
    Y for adding,
    R to remove
    L to restate list. """)
        print()               
        if n.lower() =='y':
            print()
            myList.insert(0, input('Insert what you want to add. '))
        elif n.lower() == 'r':
            print()
            name = input('Input item name you wish to remove. ')
            if name in myList:
                myList.remove(name)
        elif n.lower() == 'l':
            items(myList)
        elif n.lower() == 'n':
            sys.exit()

items(myList)
change()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
spam = ['apples', 'bananas', 'tofu', 'cats']

def makeString(l):
  stringPart1 = l[:-1] 
  stringPart2 = l[-1]
  finalString = ', '.join(stringPart1)+' and '+stringPart2
  return finalString

print(makeString(spam))
```

**RESULT**

```
apples, bananas, tofu and cats


# stringPart1 will be a list consist of following elements.
# stringPart1 = ['apples', 'bananas', 'tofu']
# 1[:-1] slice every thing from the 0 to last-1
# 
# stringPart2 will be a string.
# stringPart2 = 'cats'
# 1[-1] = return the item at the last index
```

Answer (score 0):

def comma_code(comma_list):

```
final_list = ''

for i in range(len(comma_list)-1):
    final_list = final_list  + comma_list[i] + ', '
final_list = final_list + ', and ' + comma_list[len(comma_list)-1]
print(final_list)
```

given_list = ['apples', 'bananas', 'tofu', 'cats']

comma_code(given_list)

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A proper explanation would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please edit your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you’ve made.

Answer (score 0):

There is another short way of compiling a simple code for this task:

```
def CommaCode(list):
    h = list[-2] + ' and ' + list[-1]
    for i in list[0:len(list)-2]:
        print(str(i), end = ', ')
    print(h)
```

And if you run it with the spam list to check:

```
CommaCode(spam)
apples, bananas, tofu and cats
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the simplest code to solve this problem

```
array = ['apples', 'bananas', 'tofu', 'cats']

def commaCode (array):

    print("'"+ array[0]+',',end= '') #this line for the first element

    for i in range (1,len(array)-1): #iteration for the elements from 1 until n-1
        print(array[i]+',',end='')

    print('and '+array[-1]+"'") #this for the last element

commaCode(array)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my code. I know improvements can be made, but I am just a beginner. I will be obliged if anyone provides constructive input.

```
spam = ['apples', 'bananas', 'tofu', 'cats']
def commaSpace(listValue):
   for i in range(len(listValue)):
       print(listValue[i] + ', ' , end='')
       if listValue[i] == listValue[-1]:
        print('and ' + listValue[-1])
commaSpace(spam)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm a beginner but the most practical solution seems to be with 'join' method.
My attempt:

```
def concac(arg):
words = ''
for i in arg:
    words += i
    new = ",".join(arg[0:len(arg)-1]) + " and " + arg[-1]
    return new
```

Answer (score -1):

I have come up with a rather simple code to solve this exercise. Please take a look.

```
  spam = ['apples', 'bananas', 'tofu', 'cats']
  def list_to_string(value):
      value.insert(len(value)-1,'and')
      st = '' #empty string
      for i in value:
          st = st + ', ' + i #to concatenate the list values to a single string
      print st.lstrip(', ') #lstrip - to strip off the comma and space at the beginning of the string

 list_to_string(spam) #calling the function
```

The only issue I found with this code is that, I was unable to remove the comma after 'and'.

Other wise, the code works fine.

Thank you.